# Implementing an interpreter in Haskell exercise CIS194

Tags: haskell, interpreter

I'm lerning haskell from the material that can be found [here](https://www.seas.upenn.edu/~cis194/lectures.html). I'm begining [homework 3](https://www.seas.upenn.edu/~cis194/hw/03-ADTs.pdf)  in which the objective is to write an interpreter for a simple language but I'm stuck in the first exercise:

> Before we can start evaluating Expressions and Statements
>   we need some way to store and look up the state of a variable. We
>   define a `State` to be a function of type `String -> Int`. This makes it
>   very easy to look up the value of a variable; to look up the value of
>   `"A"` in `state`, we simply call `state "A"`. Whenever we assign a variable,
>   we want to update the program `State`. Implement the following
>   function:
>
> `extend :: State -> String -> Int -> State`
>
> Hint: You can use the input State as a black box for variables other
>   than the one you are assigning.
>
> Example:
>
> `let st’ = extend st "A" 5`
>
> `in st’ "A" == 5`

I don't get what I'm supposed to be doing here. In the hint I'm not sure what "black box" means. In the example I get that `st'` is a State, but I'm not sure I get what `in st' "A" == 5` is doing.

If someone could clarify both the hint and the example for me I think I would be able to solve this exercise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Black box" means you can ignore how it's implemented and just use it. `let foo = bar in baz` binds a new variable `foo` to the expression `bar`, then results in `baz` (which may mention `foo`); presumably here the point is that the given Haskell expression should evaluate to `True` -- that is, this is a test case for your implementation.

Comment: Ohhh I see, this is more simple than I first thought. The "black box" was confusing me. Thank you!